# Как создать подобный LiveTemplates в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

В настройках есть возможность  создавать свои LiveTemplates. Создал несколько своих достаточно примитивных, но сейчас я столкнулся с проблемой. Требуется создать шаблон который в зависимости от типа и количества параметров генерирует различный код. Может кто то подсказать каким образом можно сделать такой шаблон?

А именно, если метод выглядит как то так:

```
private void unregisterUser(final String message, final int id)
```

генерировал следующий код:

```
Timber.i("unregisterUser. message: %s\nid: %d", message, id)
```

А для такого:

```
private void unregisterUser(final boolean isRegister)
```

генерировал такой

```
Timber.i("unregisterUser. isRegister: %b", isRegister)
```

То есть в зависимости от типа параметра проставлялся требуемый идентификатор (%s, %b и т.д.) и перечислялись ссылки на параметры метода

Comment: Именно так, как вы хотите вроде не получится сделать (мешает только необходимость определять типы аргументов). Возможно этот вопрос окажется полезным https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440525/idea-live-template-to-log-method-args

Comment: @Дмитрий благодар за ответ, там именно то что мне нужно, свой ответ, точнее его часть, нашел именно тут http://artfulonline.blogspot.ru/2014/03/quick-logging-with-intellij-live.html По возможности, оформите пожалуйста как ответ что бы я могу закрыть вопрос

Comment: Как сделали в итоге? Получилось без определения модификаторов %d, %s, %b?

Comment: @Дмитрий удалось сделать именно так как вы описали ниже в ответе. В итоге оказалась статья полезной, не знал что в шаблонах можно описать скрипт который будет что либо выполнять

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В точности как вы хотите вроде не получится сделать, однако что-то похожее вполне можно. Для этого:

1. Создайте новый Live Template --- `Settings/Editor/Live Templates`
2. Аббревиатуру напишите какую вам удобно, текст шаблона следующий: `Timber.i("$METHOD_NAME$. " + $METHOD_ARGUMENTS$);`, также определите контекст в котором будет доступен шаблон --- `Java`.
3. Нажмите `Edit variables`, добавьте переменную `METHOD_NAME` со значением `methodName()` и переменную `METHOD_ARGUMENTS` со значением

   ```
   `groovyScript("'\"' + _1.collect { it + ' = [\" + ' + it + ' + \"]'}.join(', ') + '\"'", methodParameters())`.
   ```

   Также для обоих переменных поставьте флажок `Skip if defined`.

Должно получится что-то примерно такое: [image: скриншот настроек]

Тогда внутри метода `private void unregisterUser(final String message, final int id)` шаблон будет разворачиваться в

```
Timber.i("unregisterUser. " + "message = [" + message + "], id = [" + id + "]");
```

Также может быть полезен [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440525/idea-live-template-to-log-method-args) вопрос, особенно вот эта [ссылка](http://artfulonline.blogspot.ru/2014/03/quick-logging-with-intellij-live.html), упомянутая в нём.